Stopped brownian motion has property $(P)$.
I have this exercise. I think I have a solution, but it is kind of weird and complicated. I'd appreciate anyone checking it (particularly the "fourth equality" that I mention below) and/or telling me if there is an easier solution.
The exercise is:

Let $B_t$ be a $\mathscr{F}_t$ Brownian motion started from zero. I want to show $B_{t\wedge 1}$ satisfies "Property $(P)$."  That is, for any fixed $p\geq 1$, there exists a constant $C$ (depending on $p$) such that for any $\mathscr{F}_t$ stopping time $T\leq 1$, we have $$E[~(B_1-B_T)^p~| \mathscr{F}_T]\leq C.$$


My proof is:
For $T\leq 1$ a stopping time, and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ write $$T^{(n)}= \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{k}{2^n}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}.$$
Then $(B_1-B_{T^{(n)}})^p$ converges pointwise to $(B_1-B_T)^p$ as $n\to \infty$, and in fact also in $L^1$ by dominated convergence since $$E \left[\sup_{t\leq 1} |B_t|^p \right]\leq \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p E[|B_1|^p]<\infty$$ by the Doob's inequality (we assume $p>1$ as the result is trivial for $p=1$).
Thus we have
$$\begin{align}
E[~(B_1-B_T)^p~| \mathscr{F}_T]&=\lim_{n\to\infty}E[(B_1-B_{T^{(n)}})^p |\mathscr{F}_T]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} E \left[\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}  \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n} \leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}(B_1-B_{k/2^n})^p|\mathscr{F}_T \right] \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}  E \left[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}(B_1-B_{k/2^n})^p|\mathscr{F}_T \right] \\ 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}  E \left[E \left[\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}(B_1-B_{k/2^n})^p|\mathscr{F}_{k/2^n}\right]|\mathscr{F}_T \right]  \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}  \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}E \left[E \left[(B_1-B_{k/2^n})^p|\mathscr{F}_{k/2^n}\right]|\mathscr{F}_T \right] \\  
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}  \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq T < \frac{k}{2^n}\right\}}E \left[(B_1-B_{k/2^n})^p \right] \\ 
&\leq E \left[\sup_{t\leq 1}(B_1-B_t)^p \right] \\ 
&<\infty
\end{align}$$
so we may take $C:=E \left[\sup_{t\leq 1}(B_1-B_t)^p \right].$ C is finite by the Doob's inequality. Above, the fourth equality is due to the fact that for any $f\in L^1$, any stopping time $T$, and any $k\geq 0$, we have
$$E \left[f\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\left\{T\leq k \right\}}|\mathscr{F}_T \right]=E \left[E \left[f\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\left\{T\leq k\right\}}|\mathscr{F}_k \right]|\mathscr{F}_T \right],$$
since for $A\in \mathscr{F}_T$, we have
$$\int_{A} f\mathbb{1}_{T\leq k} = \int_{A\cap \{T\leq k\}} E[f| \mathscr{F}_k]=\int_A \mathbb{1}_{T\leq k} E[f|\mathscr{F}_k]=\int_A E[f\mathbb{1}_{T\leq k} | \mathscr{F}_k].$$

Doob's maximal inequality holds for $p>1$. The problem says $p>0$ (or is it a typo?)

@Snoop sorry yes it's a typo. thank you.

Define the functional $f:C[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sup_{t\leq 1}|x_t-x_0|^p$. Since $\tau\leq 1$ we have
$$(B_1-B_{\tau})^p\leq \sup_{t\leq 1}|B_{t+\tau}-B_{\tau}|^p=f((B_{\tau+s})_{s\geq 0})$$
Thus $E[(B_1-B_{\tau})^p|\mathscr{F}_\tau]\leq E[f((B_{\tau+s})_{s\geq 0})|\mathscr{F}_\tau]=E[f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})]|_{B_0=B_\tau}$ by strong Markov property. Since $(B_t-B_0)_{t\geq 0}$ is a BM starting at zero for any real $B_0$, we have $E[f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})]|_{B_0=B_\tau}=E[f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})]|_{B_0=0}$. We conclude, because $E[f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})]|_{B_0=0}<\infty$ for any $p\geq 1$ (we know the distribution of $f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})$ by reflection principle - however from the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality we immediately get $E[f((B_{s})_{s\geq 0})]|_{B_0=0}\leq C_p$ for some constant $C_p$ depending from $p$).

thank you. i dont think i totally understand the $|_{B...}$ notation. could you explain  explain that?

Sure: here $E[.]|{B_0=x}$ means the law of the Brownian motion started at point $x$. Other common notation is $E_x[.]$. Here $E[.]|{B_0=B_\tau}$ indicates $E_{B_\tau}[.]$. @famousmortimer

Ok what I meant was:  Can I avoid that by using instead $f(x):=\sup_{t\leq 1}|x_t|^p$
since then $E[|B_1−B_\tau|^p|\mathscr{F}t]\leq E[f((B{\tau+s}−B_\tau){s\geq 0})|\mathscr{F}\tau]=E[f((B_{\tau+s}−B_\tau)_{s\geq 0})]$
? does that sound right?

The equality is just strong markov property isn't it?

If I am not mistaken you are using an equivalent definition of the strong Markov property (i.e. $(B_{\tau+s}-B_\tau){s\geq 0}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}\tau$). Seems legit @famousmortimer

yes, that's the one i learned. ok thank you!
